# ActionMailer not sending emails enqueued in Fake_sqs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, amazon-sqs, rails-activejob

I'm working on a Rails 4 app that sends out emails, for new registrations and such, and I'm trying to set up `SQS` to use `deliver_later` to process them through a queue. In development I'm simulating this by using [Fake_SQS](https://github.com/iain/fake_sqs).

The messages are being successfully added to the queue. If I use `binding.pry` I get (formatted nicely).

```
resp = sqs.receive_message({queue_url: "http://localhost:4568/mailers"}) =>
#<struct Aws::SQS::Types::ReceiveMessageResult
messages = [#<struct Aws::SQS::Types::Message
  message_id="95c380c7-9710-449e-beb6-19b19cc88e04",
  receipt_handle="7b51a9568a6301509459697376e867a6",
  md5_of_body="d09027c2c92b19e572766360fc627630",
  body="{\"job_class\"  : \"ActionMailer::DeliveryJob\",
         \"job_id\"     : \"6edb612c-e5f7-4cc0-8236-4ac538344c66\",
         \"queue_name\" : \"mailers\",
         \"arguments\"  : [\"UserMailer\",
                           \"test_email\",
                           \"deliver_now!\",
                           null],
         \"locale\"     : \"en\"}",
  attributes={},
  md5_of_message_attributes=nil,
  message_attributes={}>]>
```

What I'm having trouble with is then sending these emails later. I think I have to start the ActiveJob worker, but I thought that would be started automatically when using `deliver_later`. If not, how do I start it and point it at my queue properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :inline
```